# Many-to-Many Misunderstanding in Django

Tags: django, networking, many-to-many, social-media

I am new to web development so this question might not be straightforward but please bear with me. Im working on a social network in which a user could follow another user in two different ways...anwyways...i created two models to define the relationships. A many-to-many relationship as follows.

How do i make this models totally independent of each other? so lets say a user could have 500Followers and 200Guests??

i used th javascript code below to toggle the follow button but its increases both. This might not be a great overview of the problem but thats because i am new to this. but please try. I am using django by the way.

```
class Follower(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rel_from_set')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rel_to_set')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} is now a following".format(self.user_from, self.user_to) 

class Guests(models.Model):
    user_fromt = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='yel_from_set')
    user_tot = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='yel_to_set')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created',)

def __str__(self):
    return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


User.add_to_class('follows', models.ManyToManyField('self',
through=Guests, related_name='guest', symmetrical=False))

User.add_to_class('follows', models.ManyToManyField('self',
through=Follwer, related_name='guest', symmetrical=False))
```

View

```
def user_follow(request):
    user_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')
    if user_id and action:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if action == 'follow':
                Contact.objects.get_or_create(user_from=request.user,     
                 user_to=user)
                create_action(request.user, 'is now a fan of', user)
            else:
                Contact.objects.filter(user_from=request.user, 
            user_to=user).delete()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ok'})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'ko'})
        return JsonResponse({'status':'ko'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having two separate through models, have a single model with a `type` field.

Comment: Daniel Roseman. Please could you briefly elaborate on that?...i am knew to this. I am using "Django by Example" as a guide. thanks